# Way to escape syntax highlighting inside a code block?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Let's say, I'm working in a REPL environment. I want to provide an example of a specific code snippet in my README. Something like this:

````
```python 
>>> import math
>>> x = math.sqrt(64)
>>> print(f"The square root of 64 equals {x}")
The square root of 64 equals 8.0
```
````

Is there any way to escape syntax highlighting while being inside the same code block? Specifically, I want the `print` output to be unformatted.

````
```python 
>>> import math
>>> x = math.sqrt(64)
>>> print(f"The square root of 64 equals {x}")
[escape highlighting here]The square root of 64 equals 8.0[escape highlighting here]
```
````